# Gitlab-runner failing if there is Gemfile in the directory

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, fastlane

Gitlab-runner failing if there is Gemfile in the directory. This problem gets fixed when i remove from directory the file. but this file needs to be exist in the project

[image]

```
  Running with gitlab-runner 12.1.0 (de7731dd)
   on Mac-Mini f96_aywm
Using Shell executor...
00:00
Running on siab01ios.siab01.com...
00:01
Fetching changes...
00:03
 Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/gitlabrunner/builds/f96_aywm/0/reactnative/xxxx/.git/
 Created fresh repository.
 From https://gitlab.xxxx.com/reactnative/xxxx
  * [new ref]         refs/pipelines/5138   -> refs/pipelines/5138
  * [new branch]      bugfix                -> origin/x
  * [new branch]      develop               -> origin/develop
  * [new branch]      feature/xxxxx-server  -> origin/feature/x-x
  * [new branch]      feature/xxxxxxxxxx    -> origin/feature/x
  * [new branch]      feature/xxxxxxxxxxxxx -> origin/feature/x
  * [new branch]      feature/xxxxxxxxx     -> origin/feature/x
  * [new branch]      master                -> origin/master
  * [new tag]         2.0                   -> 2.0
  * [new tag]         android/2.1.0         -> android/2.1.0
  * [new tag]         android/2.1.1         -> android/2.1.1
 Checking out cd81e8c9 as feature/xxx...
 Skipping Git submodules setup
 ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

what i tried

- I renamed Gemfile to Gemfile_fix and added following variable to .gitlab-ci.yml

  variables:

  BUNDLE_GEMFILE: "Gemfile_fix"
- As another solution i tried
  I created a folder named gemfile_fix and I added Gemfile into this file, again I added the following variable to the gitlab-ci.yml file

  variables:

  ```
  BUNDLE_GEMFILE: Dir.chdir File.expand_path('gemfile_fix/Gemfile', __FILE__)
  ```

[image]

**

### gitlab-ci.yml

**

```
stages:
  - setup
  #- test
  - beta
  - production
  - tag
  - appstore

variables:
  LC_ALL: 'en_US.UTF-8'
  LANG: 'en_US.UTF-8'
  BUNDLE_GEMFILE: "Gemfile_fix"

# Setup Lanes

Node:
  stage: setup
  artifacts:
    paths: 
      - ./node_modules
    expire_in: 6h
  script: yarn install
  tags: 
    - reactnative

# Test Lanes 

# iOS Test:
#   stage: beta
#   script:
#     - bundle config set path './tmp-fastlane-ci-bundle'
#     - react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
#     - bundle exec fastlane ios beta --env test
#   tags: 
#     - reactnative
#   only: 
#     - develop
#     - /^feature/    

Android Test:
  stage: beta
  script:
    - echo "$BUNDLE_GEMFILE"    
    - bundle config set path './tmp-fastlane-ci-bundle'    
    - bundle exec npx jetifier
    - react-native bundle --platform android --dev true --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
    - export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/share/android-sdk 
    - export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
    - echo $KEYSTORE_FILE | base64 -D > debug.keystore
    - export KEY_LOCATION=$(PWD)/debug.keystore
    - export KEYSTORE_PASS=$KEYSTORE_PASSWORD
    - export KEY_ALIAS=$KEY_ALIAS
    - export KEY_PASS=$KEY_PASSWORD
    - bundle exec fastlane android beta --env test
  tags: 
    - reactnative
  only: 
    - develop
    - /^feature/
```

Comment: Which image are you using to run the job?

Comment: Sorry, i didnt understand @SergioTanaka

Comment: iam using fastlane if you mean it

Comment: in your .gitlab-ci.yml you need to choose which image you'll use to run your job. could you paste the content of that file?

Comment: I added the contents of the .gitlab-ci.yml file @SergioTanaka. Sorry but i still dont understand about Image. I am very new developer if you can give example maybe i can answer